# Tablesorter can't apply search criteria on updateComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, tablesorter

I've got a "tablesorter table" containing a category names in the first column. I filter the rows using shortcut buttons which trigger the specific "search" actions depending on which one is active:

```
function do_filtering() {
    var category = $('#categories .active a').attr('data-filter-text');
    var columns = [];
    columns[0] = category;
    $('table').trigger('search', [columns]);
}
```

Contents of the table may change. Until now I triggered on the table two events: "updateCell" and "search" and it got properly updated.

I need to separate these calls:

- "updateCell" would be triggered by the cell editor (attached by a "sorter" for that specific columns' content)
- "search" would be triggered after the cell is updated.

Unfortunately filtering in the "updateComplete" handler doesn't work, please see: http://jsfiddle.net/8cg4f/352/

How can I retain the search criteria after updating the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem seems to be that since the filter inputs are empty, the filter widget is showing all rows after the update. I have two solutions, the second one probably being the better one because the first method causes flickering:

1) Add a `setTimeout` in the callback, with a time of 1 millisecond ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/8cg4f/355/)):

```
    $('td').click(function () {
        resort = false;
        $("table").trigger('updateCell', [$(this).closest('td'), resort, function(table){
            setTimeout(function(){ do_filtering(); }, 1);
        }]);
    });
```

2) Update the filters, and hide the filter row ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/8cg4f/356/)):

CSS

```
.tablesorter-filter {
    display: none;
}
```

Code

```
function do_filtering() {
    var category = $('#categories .active a').attr('data-filter-text');
    $('.tablesorter-filter:first').val(category).trigger('search');
}

$('td').click(function () {
    resort = false;
    $("table").trigger('updateCell', [$(this).closest('td'), resort, function(table){
        do_filtering();
    }]);
});
```

Comment: The second solution works even without the function(table) passed with the updateCell event. Why did you add it to the array?

Comment: I added it to the array as a callback function... I looked in the docs and I guess I forgot to include that fact =( Sorry.